# Using simple form for with bootstrap: bootstrap wrapper doesn't apply

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, simple-form

I want to display a form with the bootstrap classes (see https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#twitter-bootstrap)

I installed simple form with bootstrap argument:

```
rails generate simple_form:install --bootstrap
```

In my form:

```
<%= simple_form_for(resource,
                    :as => resource_name,
                    :url => registration_path(resource_name),
                    :html => {:class => 'form-horizontal'}) do |f| %>
    <%= devise_error_messages! %>

    <%= f.label :email %>
    <%= f.email_field :email %>
    ...
```

And the generated HTML looks like this:

```
<label class="email optional control-label" for="user_email">Email</label>
<input id="user_email" name="user[email]" size="30" type="email" value="">
```

(No wrapper tags).

Why the wrapper tags are not applied ?

---

*What I tried:*

Uninstalling and reinstalling the gem:

```
bundle update; bundle install; bundle;
rails d simple_form:install
rails generate simple_form:install --bootstrap
```

I checked that the simple_form_bootstrap.rb config file is called when the server starts; and it is.

I tried to force the wrapper to bootstrap in the form (still no wrapper tags):

```
<%= simple_form_for(resource,
                    :as => resource_name,
                    wrapper: :bootstrap,
                    ...
```

Answer (score 2):

`f.label` and `f.email_field` do not use wrappers. `f.input` does.

By replacing

```
<%= f.label :email %>
<%= f.email_field :email %>
```

with

```
<%= f.input :email %>
```

wrappers are applied.